# How to remove tashkeel from a string in lua?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk, arabic

I'm doing a simple function that should remove tashkeel from arabic text, the replace technique works for english, but not for arabic, what would you suggest?

lua code:-

```
function replacePartOfString(arg,old,new)
  local zzz = arg.gsub(arg, old, new) 
  return zzz
end

function wordLengthIgnoringTashkeel(arg)
  local tashkeelArray = {"َ","ً","ُ","ٌ","ِ","ٍ","ْ","َ"}

  local tempWord = arg

  print("tempWord Before"..tempWord)
  for x=1,#tashkeelArray do
      replacePartOfString(tempWord,tashkeelArray[x],"")
  end
  print("tempWord After"..tempWord)
end
```

> result
>
> tempWord Beforeاليَوْمَ tempWord Afterاليَوْمَ

while the expected result

> expected result
>
> tempWord Beforeاليَوْمَ tempWord Afterاليوم

Comment: Why did you put android and ios tags?

Comment: You have forgotten to catch the result returned by your function: `tempWord = replacePartOfString(...)`

Comment: @jonathanrz : because i use corona sdk.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff : right, add an answer so i accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works

```
function replacePartOfString(arg,old,new) 
  return arg.gsub(arg, old, new) 
end

function wordLengthIgnoringTashkeel(arg)
  local tashkeelArray = {"َ","ً","ُ","ٌ","ِ","ٍ","ْ","َّ"}
  local tempWord = arg
  for x=1,#tashkeelArray do
      tempWord = replacePartOfString(tempWord,tashkeelArray[x],"")
  end
  return #tempWord
end
```

Comment: I guess my answer is same as yours but will be nice if you accept it. I had a similar problem where I wanted to http post arabil letters to google and it didnt work. I had to make a local chracter table and send numbers to google and print equivalent table value. I can tell you the problem is due to Arabic word being handled by lua possibly as non standard.

Answer (score 1):

function wordLengthIgnoringTashkeel(arg)
  local tashkeelArray = {"َ","ً","ُ","ٌ","ِ","ٍ","ْ","َ"}

local tempWord = arg

print("tempWord Before"..tempWord)
  for x=1,#tashkeelArray do
      tempWord = string.gsub(tempWord,tashkeelArray[x],"")
  end
  print("tempWord After"..tempWord)
end

wordLengthIgnoringTashkeel("يَوْمَ")

Comment: You can always improve you answers by formatting them, in your case, adding a code block by adding 4 spaces. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help A little bit of an explanation would help as well

Answer (score 0):

This code maybe help you, it's worked with me, for one file:

```
perl  -CS -pe 's/[\x{064B}-\x{0650}]|[\x{0618}-\x{061A}]|[\x{0652}-\x{0653}]|[\x{0652}-\x{0653}]+//g' < "$f" > "$f.txt" ;
```

for all files in folder:

```
for f in *.txt; do 

perl  -CS -pe 's/[\x{064B}-\x{0650}]|[\x{0618}-\x{061A}]|[\x{0652}-\x{0653}]|[\x{0652}-\x{0653}]+//g' < "$f" > "$f.txt" ;

done
```

Regards